# Keep io_service alive

Tags: boost, boost-asio

My prefered way to use an `io_service` is to create a thread on application start that executes the `io_service`'s run method. The problem is, if there is no task for `io_service`, its run method returns immediately and the thread terminates.

As you can see from the [chat_client.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp)

```
...
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
...
chat_client c(io_service, iterator);
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

the thread is started **after** some async task is added to `io_service`. This is done in the `chat_clients`'s constructor.

My question is: Is there a way to create the thread **before** some task is added to `io_service`, i. e.

```
// create io_service and thread on application start
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
// add some task to io_service
chat_client c(io_service, iterator);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said, its run method returns immediately because it has no work.
You need to use **boost::asio::io_service::work** . Think of it as a dummy work item, so **io_service::run** never runs out of work, and thus doesn't return immediately.

Example:

```
    auto work = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(m_ioservice);
    m_ioservice.run();
```

Some people prefer an **io_service::run** to always block, waiting for work. Other people prefer the behavior Asio gives you by default.

Comment: in addition, to stop the application, I use `work.reset();` before `t.join();`